# Ipython notebook align Latex equations in Ipython.Display module

Tags: python, html, css, latex, ipython

I am using ipython notebook to write latex equations with the following modules

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
```

a simple example code might look like:

```
display(Math('a = \\frac{1}{2}'))
display(Math('b = \\frac{1}{3}'))
display(Math('c = \\frac{1}{4}'))
```

Which would output:

```
a = 1/2
b = 1/3
c = 1/4
```

in a pretty print format. Is there a way that I can somehow align this in columns like:

```
a = 1/2      b = 1/3      c = 1/4
```

? I know that the markup allows HTML usage, but this markup is entered into the input for a code-based cell. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with LaTeX, but the notebook does allow you to use things like `\begin{align}`, allowing you to organize things into columns by separating them with `&` symbols. For example, this works if you enter it into a Markdown cell:

```
$$
\begin{align}
a = \frac{1}{2} && b = \frac{1}{3} && c = \frac{1}{4} \\
a && b && c
\end{align}
$$
```

This also works using `display(Math())`, e.g.:

```
display(Math(
r"""
\begin{align}
a = \frac{1}{2} && b = \frac{1}{3} && c = \frac{1}{4} \\
a && b && c \\
1 && 2 && 3
\end{align}
"""))
```

Giving you this output:

[image]

Comment: Marius, my problem with that is that I am using a module that relies on display(Math()) to make the equations and unfortunately, it seems that adding in the && into the display(Math()) results in the output not working..

Comment: `display(Math())` works fine for me, at least for your simple example- see the new code I've added. If you can figure out the difference between my example and the thing you're actually having trouble with, I might be able to help, otherwise I'm not really sure what's going on.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! It looks like the \begin{align} and \end{align} are necessary for the Math() to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's possible there's something different about my environment, but I found that double dollar signs $$ ... $$ automatically inserted \begin{equation} tags. Using single dollar signs $ ... $ resolved the problem. I also only needed single &s for alignment